# Getting Uncaught TypeError "some object" is not a function in basic find request

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using EmberData with an Express backend which is connected to MongoDB with Mongoose.

My versions are as follows

```
version: 1.13.7
node: 0.12.0
npm: 2.13.3
os: darwin x64
"ember": "1.13.6",
"ember-data": "1.13.7",
express@4.13.3
```

I have a route file at `app/routes/commands/index.js` which has a model hook like so

```
model: function() {return this.store.findAll('command');}
```

The template at `app/templates/commands/index.hbs` looks like this

```
{{#each model as |command|}}
<p>Trigger: {{trigger}}</p>
<p>Response: {{response}}</p>
<p>Permission: {{permission}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

In the console I see this error on the `/commands` page

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.record.trigger.apply is not a function
ember$data$lib$system$model$internal$model$$InternalModel._triggerDeferredTriggers @ internal-model.js:439
Queue.invoke @ ember.debug.js:910
Queue.flush @ ember.debug.js:974
DeferredActionQueues.flush @ ember.debug.js:770
Backburner.end @ ember.debug.js:160
Backburner.run @ ember.debug.js:228
run @ ember.debug.js:20075
ember$data$lib$system$adapter$$default.extend.ajax.Ember.RSVP.Promise.hash.success @ rest-adapter.js:831
jQuery.Callbacks.fire @ jquery.js:3148
jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith @ jquery.js:3260
done @ jquery.js:9314
jQuery.ajaxTransport.send.callback @ jquery.js:9718
```

I've not seen this error before so I'm getting a little thrown off. When I look in the ember inspector in the `data` tab I see the commands that the express server is sending back so the connection is working and returning results just fine. Interestingly it seems to only be getting one record though., even though there are two in the database.

For reference here is the adapter and serializer

```
// app/adapters/application.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: 'http://localhost:3000',
  namespace: 'api/v1'
});

// app/serializers/application.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: '_id'
});
```

The response from the server looks like this

```
{
  "commands": [
    {
      "_id": "55d3772f572ff504e3f2f236",
      "trigger": "!steam",
      "response": "http://steamcommunity.com/id/itsmatax",
      "permission": null,
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "55d37a1c83082a06e5283bb0",
      "trigger": "!test",
      "response": "testing",
      "permission": null,
      "__v": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

The `command` model is defined in ember as so

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  trigger: DS.attr('string'),
  response: DS.attr('string'),
  permission: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Here is the repo for the server

https://github.com/Jordan4jc/super-fly-twitch-bot/tree/express

(There are some left over files from the master branch, but the `routes`, `models`, and `server.js` are the main express files)

And here is the repo for the client

https://github.com/Jordan4jc/super-fly-twitch-bot-client

Comment: Couldn't you just do:

`{{#each command in model}}
    <p>Trigger: {{command.trigger}}</p>
    <p>Response: {{command.response}}</p>
    <p>Permission: {{command.permission}}</p>
{{/each}}`

Comment: Doesn't really matter how I try to display it in the template I still get the weird error in the console

Comment: What adapter do you use? Can you post a response from your backend?

Comment: Hey I posted the adapter, serializer and response @GennadyDogaev

Comment: How is your `command` model defined? Could you please post it too?

Comment: @GennadyDogaev I added links to the full repo's, for clarification are you asking for the ember model or the express model (I assume the ember model)

Comment: @Jordan ember model, which I don't see defined in your repo. Try to define model in app/models/command.js, as described here http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/models/defining-models/

Comment: @GennadyDogaev My fault, forgot to push, it's there now. I'm also adding it to the original question

Comment: I don't know what may be wrong. I would suggest to rename a serializer from application.js to command.js. Maybe it will help somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove the "s" from the folder name and file name for your "command" component? Usually if you have a "command.js" defined for a component, and all of its sub routes should be put under a "command" folder.